# Replacing the column values based on Regex matching SQL

Tags: sql, regex, replace, hana, insert-update

I have my HANA SQL query

```
select 
  replace_regexpr('[ \t]+$' in "id" with '' OCCURRENCE ALL) 
from TABLE1
```

that will display the replaced trailing whitespaces for the column ID without updating the original values in the table.

How can I extend this query to actually save these replaced values back to the table corresponding to the respective IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update TABLE1
set "id" = replace_regexpr('[ \t]+$' in "id" with '' OCCURRENCE ALL) 
WHERE "id"  LIKE_REGEXPR ' [ \t]+$'
```

This will set values of column `"id"` based on the previous value in this column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET "id" = replace_regexpr('[ \t]+$' in "id" with '' OCCURRENCE ALL)
```

If you only want to replace trailing white spaces, you may want to consider function `LTRIM`:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET "id" = LTRIM("id")
```